# tcpdump with payload that is sent

Tags: linux, wireshark, tcpdump

Hi is there a way to get a tcp dump with data that is sent in a request or by the request payload. Since there are too many network elements and request traffic it would be really helpful if the capture could be narrowed down initially.

Comment: Have you looked through the examples here? https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters

Comment: What do you want to capture?  Your question is very vague.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to filter for text string in TCP payload like this:

```
tcp contains "text"
```

or

```
frame contains "text"
```

Comment: "Contains" isn't a valid macro under BPF.  Your solution would only work with Tshark.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer That's one way to do that. Didn't say it is the only way.